# Vim - Add a character to X next lines

Tags: vim, delete, text-editor

I would like to add a # to the beginning of the 15 next lines (to comment everything).
I know how to do it for 1 line : i -> #.
My second question would be the opposite, how to delete the first character of the 15 next lines ?
at the moment, i'm doing `r1l` (remove 1 letter) for each line.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please try to ask only one question at a time even if the question are related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the character press the following keystrokes:

- ctrl-v
- down arrow (15 times or 15G to go to line number 15 directly)
- I (Capital letter)
- #
- esc

To delete the character press the following keystrokes:

- ctrl-v
- down arrow (15 times or 15G to go to line number 15 directly)
- x

Please pay attention to lower and capital letters. They are important in vim.

Comment: Your answer to delete the first character us working great !
But the answer to add a character to each line is not working :(

Comment: I edited the answer. Check it once more.

Comment: My bad, I didnt press esc and # only appearded on the first line. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **search and replace** and add a range to it:

`:.,15s/^/#/`

To undo just:

`:.,15s/^#//`